# Run command before end of each frame

Tags: beamer, etoolbox

I've modified `\item` to insert a `\vfill` after each occurrence to space out bulleted lists on slides so they do not cluster in the center following this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249958/179330). However, to balance out my vertical spacing, I have to include a `\vfill` at the end of each slide.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I'd like to avoid this repeated effort by modifying the `frame` environment to automatically include a `\vfill` before the `\end{frame}`:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\vfill % I want this automatically inserted
\end{frame}
```

Thus, I need to run a command *before* the end of each frame. The top answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226319/run-a-command-at-end-of-each-frame) details how to use [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox?lang=en) to tap into the low level commands in [`beamerbaseframe.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseframe.sty) to add arbitrary TeX code to the end of each slide. However, I've tried modifying the provided code and it results in placing a test string *after* the `frame` environment ends, resulting in a blank slide after each slide with the test string at the top, or before, with a blank slide before each slide with the test string at the top. Needless to say since my test string is appearing on slides by itself, when I replace it with `\vfill`, my the items on my slides are not spaced out like they should be.

I don't understand `beamerbaseframe.sty` well enough to know which command I should be patching to achieve my desired outcome. Where should I be looking to patch to add a command directly before the end of every frame?

MWE with my attempt at solving this and demonstrating the spacing I'd like to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@doseveralframes}% <cmd>
{\beamer@reseteecodes}% <search>
{\beamer@reseteecodes\textbf{aaa}}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
    \olditem\vfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} % this slide is spaced how I want
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item bar
        \item baz
    \end{itemize}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! To me this seems like an XY question. You may really be looking for `\begin{frame}[t]`, i.e. the `t` option makes the contents "move up" (as if there was a `\vfill` at the end).

Comment: This doesn't center it the way a `\vfill` at the end does, probably because each `\item` is now followed by a `\vfill`.

Comment: Some good soul pinged me and is wondering if you are looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369597/194703, then.

Comment: This does exactly what I want, thank you! It even spreads out items slightly more fully than my previous approach.