# Beamer: stretch space between items in itemised list within columns

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize

I've been following the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369630/174314) to get the items in my itemised lists to spread neatly across the vertical space in my slides.

However, placing an `itemize` environment inside a `column` environment makes the spacing revert to become very tight again. I frequently have text on the left side of my frames, and images/figures on the right, as some explanation.

How might I further patch the linked answer so that this works within columns, too?

Comment: You can find a solution which also works for columns at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=832#a983